# No internet connection after computer went to sleep with openvpn running

Tags: wireless, 20.04, vpn, openvpn

I have launched my VPN using

```
sudo openvpn /path/to/conf.ovpn
```

It works fine. Then, my computer goes to sleep and I can’t load internet pages (it times out) when I wake it up.

ping is working fine. I tried turning my Wifi on and off, I tried

```
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi && sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

Also:

```
sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service
```

But none of that worked.

This is not the first time it happened and every time it did, I needed to reboot my computer for my Wifi connection to work properly again.

How can I solve my problem without rebooting?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to reboot. Just disconnect your VPN connection, then re-connect.

Comment: That's kinda what I did: `ps ax | grep "openvpn"` and then `sudo kill -9 PID` and it does not work.

Comment: How did you start it? The way you posted it in your question suggests you must have an open console with openvpn running, have you tried just killing that with Ctrl+C?

Comment: Yes, I tried and it does not kill itself. I do succeed to kill it successfully by using CTRL+C when my computer does not go to sleep, but when it does go to sleep, this operation is impossible

Comment: And I don't want to use the VPN anymore: I just want to use my "normal" connection which does not work.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow - just kill the VPN connection after the PC wakes up again. Alternatively, import the ovpn file in Network Manager, and then disconnect and reconnect the VPN connection from there.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I faced the same problem. My VPN was connected then I pressed CTRL + ALT + F11 then It went into some kind of sleep mode, and then I had to restart my laptop after long pressing power button. So then my internet and Gs connect stopped working, I uninstalled proton vpn but the problem still persisted, So what I did was just reinstalled protonvpn but how? my internet was not working, so I just entered `nameserver 8.8.8.8` and `nameserver 8.8.4.4` in my `/etc/resolv.conf` file and then I didn't reload networkmanager and my internet was working but as soon as I reload networkmanager or restart my laptop, resolv.conf changes to its default and internet stopped working. So I just changed resolv.conf file and then installed protonvpn again and tried connecting it, then I got a error message that you need to disconnect other vpn service or buy premium, So that means after uninstalling it, VPN still was in act somewhere so I just closed protonvpn and ran `sudo killall vpn` and then `systemctl restart NetworkManager` and viola my internet and Gs connect were working again!!!.

I just wrote the whole scenario above so that someone with this problem doesn't get confused by complex commands answers.